# Android Build keep failing with build hint telephony

Tags: codenameone

I want to make the App work only for Android phones and not on tablets so I tried to add the following build hint telephony() to make the App work on Phone for Android under xpermissions:
""

I'm attaching the generated XML with telephony hint added twice one with false(default) and duplicate added with true(added by me).I'm not sure where is the option to replace the default build hint which added with false value. I'm suspecting that was causing the issue for build to fail on the server.

Please find the generated log below:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.LocalNotificationPublisher" ></receiver>
    <service android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.BackgroundFetchHandler" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneBackgroundFetchActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <activity android:name="com.codename1.location.CodenameOneBackgroundLocationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <service android:name="com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationHandler" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.codename1.location.GeofenceHandler" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.codename1.media.AudioService" android:exported="false" />    </application>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"  android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"  android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/></manifest>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if you included the opening brackets of the XML and how this was added. If you added this directly to the properties file you probably didn't do this correctly. Notice that the build failure log prints out the full generated XML for the manifest so you can see what we got from you. We will need the full log to help.

Comment: Shai,. I have updated the generated XML file and noticed telephony hint was default added as false and I have added the hint with true again. I don't know from where false is getting added automatically which causes the issue. build hint should be added for codename1.arg.android.xpermissions?

Comment: I have update the issue description to understand the problem better. Please let me know if anyone having same issue

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include a manifest entry that's already included. We always mark dependencies as required `false`. That means the permission is desired but that the app will not fail if the permission is revoked. That's generally good practice as the `true` flag for required is probably a mistake especially in a cross platform application.

Comment: Got it Shai. In that case, what should I do if I want to release the App only for Phones and not for Tablets. What kind of Android permissions should be used to make the App work for  different screen sizes of the phone.

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to phone sizes?

Comment: Shai, I have used following build hint in codenameone_settings.properties file for IOS release to make App only install on iphones and not on ipads.I'm using telephony build hint as work around to stop the App download on larger screens like Ipad.<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key><array><string>telephony</string></array> similarly, I'm trying to use         <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" /> for google play, so that App installs on Android Phones only and will not install on Tablets.But I'm not able to override false to true.Am I doing wrong

Comment: We don't currently support that. Please file an RFE to add the ability to force required build hints and we'll try to address that.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Will do. There is another note related this was, setting the target device(Xcode project properties) is missing in CN1. Not sure if I didn't if something like that exists. We have option like that, this process will be lot easier for developer who wants to release the App specific to some devices.

Comment: I don't follow? Setting the target device on iOS is available in the iOS section in Codename One Settings. You can pick ipad, iphone or both